# Why does a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ not contain every real number?

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory, real-numbers

Let $F$ be a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$. Since the completeness axiom holds in $\mathbb{R}$, it will also hold in $F$. But every real number can be represented as an infinite cauchy series of rational numbers, and $F$ must contain $\mathbb{Q}$. It then follows that because $F$ is closed under addition and multiplication, it contains every real number.
But... that's not true. So what's the mistake here?

Comment: Why would a subfield be complete?

Comment: @Thomas Ahh I see it now. Thanks. I thought that since every cauchy sequence $a_n$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$, it would also do that if $a_n \in F$ for all $n$. But of course now the limit of the sequence need not be in $F$...

Comment: @Vincent A subfield is complete if and only if it is closed in $\Bbb{R}$. Now, every subfield of $\Bbb{R}$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$ (because it contains $\Bbb{Q}$), hence being closed is equivalent of being the whole $\Bbb{R}$. This means that $\Bbb{R}$ is the unique complete subfield of itself: and this is the reason why it has proper subfields not containing every real number.

Comment: note that by replacing in the definition of completeness the Cauchy sequences by the definable Cauchy sequences, you get something quite different.